# Welches ist die derzeitige Hauptbedeutung des deutschen Wortes 'Girl'?

Tags: meaning, anglicism

Der Duden listet

> [Girl, das](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Girl)
>
> Bedeutungsübersicht
>   1. (umgangssprachlich) Mädchen
>   2. einer Tanzgruppe, einer Revue (1b) angehörende Tänzerin

Dieses *Wort* scheint seit den Zwanziger Jahren in Deutschland etabliert zu sein ([Artikel von 1929](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/47268/26786)).

Nun behauptete aber zum Beispiel einer der Debattenteilnehmer pro und kontra Anglizismen in einer [Zeitschrift](https://www.geo.de/magazine/geo-wissen/13582-geo-wissen-nr-40-10-07-das-geheimnis-der-sprache) ([Krämer vs Kekule](https://www.abendblatt.de/kultur-live/article107345079/Goethe-Setzen-Fuenf.html)) das "Mädchen" eben nicht dieser Bedeutung entspräche.

Als Beispiel sei die deutsche 'Übersetzung' des Romans [Girls of Riyadh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girls_of_Riyadh) genannt. Das eigentlich naheliegende "Mädchen von Riad" für den Titel wäre also nach Meinung einiger gerade sehr schlecht übersetzt worden, weil mit Girls eben "junge Frauen" (mit weiteren Bedeutungen, zum Beispiel 'Unabhängigkeit' etc) gemeint seien. Der gewählte Titel für dieses Buch war dann auch "Die Girls von Riad".

Ohne das konkrete Übersetzungsbeispiel übermäßig zu bemühen:

Ist 'das Girl' ein umgangssprachliches Synonym zu (junges, kleines) 'Mädchen' oder mehr zu (junge, $Spezialisierungsadjektive$) Frau?

---

<sub>Es geht *nicht* um allgemeines *Sprachniveau* oder pro/kontra *Bewertung* des Wortes. Mehr: *Wenn* es benutzt wird, was ist das dann?</sub>

Answer (score 6):

'Girl' ist kein gängiges Wort zu Mädchen in der Deutschen Sprache. Ich wüsste keine Situation, bei der 'Girl' passend wäre. Mädchen oder junge Frau ist passender.

Was jedoch erwähnenswert ist, in der Jugendsprache, verwendet man manchmal aber eher selten das Wort 'Girl'. Z.B.: Siehst du das Girl dort hinten?

Comment: re Jugendsprache: Ist das aktuell noch so? Das klingt für mich nach Bravo-Foto-Lovestory aus den 90ern oder früher ...

Comment: Da ich selber noch jugendlicher (17) bin, kann ich das bestätigen. Ist jetzt nicht gebräuchlich, manche benutzen es, manche nicht.

Answer (score 3):

Wenn man bei dwds.de [in den Korpora nach *Girl* sucht](https://www.dwds.de/r?q=Girl;corpus=public;format=full;date-start=1990;date-end=2018;genre=Gebrauchsliteratur;genre=Wissenschaft;genre=Zeitung;genre=Belletristik;sort=date_desc;limit=50) (ich habe mal den Zeitbereich auf "nicht vor 1990" eingeschränkt), finden sich zunächst einmal sehr viele Eigennamen von Musikgruppen und ähnlichem, Werktitel (von Filmen, Büchern, Gemälden, Musikstücken etc.), sowie feststehende Begriffe wie "Bond Girl". Einzig unter den Werktiteln gibt es dabei einen nennenswerten Anteil von eindeutig als "weibliches Kind" (Das Wort *Mädchen* finde ich hier problematisch, da es — auch in Kombination mit *jung* oder *klein* — oft in der Bedeutung "junge Frau" gebraucht wird) gemeinten Verwendungen, ansonsten überwiegt deutlich "junge Frau".

Wenn man diese (die, da meist ursprünglich englischsprachig, wohl wenig Aussagekraft für die Verwendung von *Girl* im Deutschen haben) aussortiert, bleiben fast nur erwachsene *Girls* übrig: Neben Profisportlerinnen vor allem Tänzerinnen, attraktive oder sich lasziv kleidende/verhaltende junge Frauen, oder solche, die geküsst werden, mit denen man Sex hat, ...

Einzig der mehrfach erwähnte [Girls' Day](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girls%27_Day), der sich an minderjährige *Girls* richtet, sticht noch hervor, ist ja aber ebenfalls ein ursprünglich englischsprachiger Eigenname.

Answer (score 1):

"Girl" passt im Englischen sowohl auf kleine Mädchen als auch junge Frauen. Wenn es im Deutschen benutzt wird, gilt i.A. dasselbe.

"Mädchen" wird normalerweise nicht (mehr) benutzt, um eine junge Frau zu benennen.

Comment: Den ersten Absatz hätte ich halt auch so vermutet, aber mindestens ein Kritiker und ein Verlag scheinen da halt anderer Meinung zu sein: 'Girl kann keinesfalls ein kleines Mädchen sein'?

Answer (score 1):

Gehe ich bei Chic&Assig durch die Kinderabteilung, steht dort *Boys* und *Girls* an den Kleiderständern. In anderen Kaufhäusern sieht das ähnlich aus.